# Bash -- compactly unpack elements from array?

Tags: bash

Is there a more compact alternative to

```
arr=( 1 2 3 )
e1=${arr[0]}
e2=${arr[1]}
e3=${arr[2]}
```

?

Something like,

```
e1, e2, e3=${arr[@]}
```

Comment: How are you assigning to the array in the first place? It's likely to make more sense to fix at that point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good question! My script receives a string like `12,343,564`. I then convert it to an array of 3 elements: `arr=(${input//,/ })`. Then I wannna unpack `arr`.

Comment: Don't do `arr=(${...})` in the first place. `IFS=, read -r one two three _ <<<"$input"` is cleaner, more direct, less buggy (for instance, if you had `input='1,2,*'`, you'd get an `arr` with a list of filenames in it due to glob expansion happening at the same point where string-splitting does). BTW, in the above, the `_` soaks up any items after the third -- so if you had `12,343,565,foobar,baz`, then `foobar,baz` would be assigned to `_` rather than appended to the same element with `565`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What if my scrip relies heavily on the assumption that space is the IFS?

Comment: `IFS=, read` changes `IFS` only for the duration of the one `read` command. It doesn't impact any other part of your script.

Comment: And if your script is relying on string-splitting (the primary behavior controlled by IFS), it almost certainly has other bugs as well. Consider reading through [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) -- and take the warning at the very top to heart. (BTW, pitfall #50 is directly on-point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, *asking this question* implies that you shouldn't be using an array for your data in the first place.

That said, the following function is reusable and *correct* -- with no caveats around which data it can and can't be used for:

```
array_to_vars() {
  declare -n _arr=$1
  local var
  for var; do
    shift || return
    printf -v "$var" %s "$1"
  done
}
```

...usable as:

```
# put first element of arr into e1, second into e2, third into e3
# disregard the rest
array_to_vars arr e1 e2 e3
```

It's not as short as one might like, but it's less likely to cause bugs as something that works only for data not containing a sigil.

---

Let's say you're populating it like so:

```
read -r -a arr < <(command-that-generates-a-list)
```

You could replace that with:

```
read -r e1 e2 e3
```

---

Or let's say it's:

```
arr=( )
while read -r line; do
  arr+=( "$line" )
done < <(command-that-generates-a-list)
```

You could that replace that with:

```
{ read -r e1; read -r e2; read -r e3; } < <(command-that-generates-a-list)
```

or with:

```
{ IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' e1 e2 e3; } < <(command-that-generates-a-list && printf '\0')
```

---

Or let's say it's:

```
arr=(${string//,/ })
```

...in that case, it would be simpler and more correct (avoiding undesired behaviors like glob expansion -- see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29)) to use:

```
IFS=, read -r e1 e2 e3 <<<"$string"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have whitespaces in your array element then you can use `read` using default `IFS` value (whitespace) in shell:

```
arr=( 1 2 3 )

# unset IFS to default value it has been set earlier
unset IFS

# read content in 3 variables
read e1 e2 e3 <<< "${arr[*]}"

# examine the content of variables
declare -p e1 e2 e3
declare -- e1="1"
declare -- e2="2"
declare -- e3="3"
```

Comment: Neat. Much better than what I'm doing!

Comment: `<<< "${arr[@]}"` is well into the area of unspecified behavior. I'd at least suggest `<<< "${arr[*]}"` to be explicit to readers about how this works (putting the first character of `$IFS` between each element), and to reduce the syntactic ambiguity. (I'd also suggest `read -r` to avoid mangling backslashes, and perhaps specifying a single-character value for IFS to reduce the number of potential datums that will cause values to be read incorrectly).

Comment: "If you don't have whitespace" is a big assumption for an array, which is typically used *because* its elements contain whitespace.

Comment: From OP's question it appears only numbers are being stored in array.